# Writing list to text file not making new lines python

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble writing to text file. Here's my code snippet.

```
ram_array= map(str, ram_value)
cpu_array= map(str, cpu_value)
iperf_ba_array= map(str, iperf_ba)
iperf_tr_array= map(str, iperf_tr)


#with open(ram, 'w') as f:
    #for s in ram_array:
        #f.write(s + '\n')

#with open(cpu,'w') as f:
    #for s in cpu_array:
        #f.write(s + '\n')

with open(iperf_b,'w') as f:
    for s in iperf_ba_array:
        f.write(s+'\n')
    f.close()   
with open(iperf_t,'w') as f:
    for s in iperf_tr_array:
        f.write(s+'\n')
    f.close()
```

The ram and cpu both work flawlessly, however when writing to a file for iperf_ba and iperf_tr they always come out look like this:

```
[45947383.0, 47097609.0, 46576113.0, 47041787.0, 47297394.0]
```

Instead of

```
1

2

3
```

They're both reading from global lists. The cpu and ram have values appended 1 by 1, but otherwise they look exactly the same pre processing.

Here's how they're made

```
filename= "iperfLog_2015_03_12_20:45:18_123_____tag_33120L06.csv"
write_location= self.tempLocation()
location=(str(write_location) + str(filename)); 


df = pd.read_csv(location, names=list('abcdefghi'))

transfer = df.h
transfer=transfer[~transfer.isnull()]#uses pandas to remove nan
transfer=transfer.tolist()

length= int(len(transfer))
extra= length-1

del transfer[extra]

bandwidth= df.i
bandwidth=bandwidth[~bandwidth.isnull()]
bandwidth=bandwidth.tolist()


del bandwidth[extra]

iperf_tran.append(transfer)
iperf_band.append(bandwidth)
```

Comment: If you're using `with open`, don't close your files - that's handled automatically.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just tried adding it to see if it made a difference.

Comment: I guess `iperf_ba` is a list with one list element.

Comment: I've edited my question to include how they're made. Maybe that's some clue.

Comment: you need to use .extend(list) if you want to add a list to a list :-)

Comment: ...I'm almost mad at you for how easy that was. I had already spent an hour trying a million things.

If you use this as an answer I'll mark it as best, thank you my friend.

Comment: hehe, don't worry, we're all spending hours debugging/chasing classy-stupid-me mistakes somedays :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[from comment]

you need to use .extend(list) if you want to add a list to a list - and don't worry: we're all spending hours debugging/chasing classy-stupid-me mistakes sometimes ;)